# How to trim a video in android using UI?

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, trim

I want to **trim a video** in android while its playing using a seek bar where user can select the duration (for example : video trim in [AndroVid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androvid) android app).

Is it possible to implement it using Android's video view?

I am also using **FFMPEG**, so once user selects the duration, i can trim using FFMPEG code. But any pointers on how this can be done on UI like AndroiVid is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, in Android you can implement a [RangeSeekBar](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) with the start and end of your video trim

Comment: Great! I was looking for the exact stuff. I tried implementing it, but can you help me how can i set position of two thumbs and make it move with the video(`sync it with video`) ?

Comment: With RangeSeekBar you can set the position and after, convert this info in values to [trim the video with ffmpeg](http://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video)

Comment: No but the question is how do i sync video with range seek bar?

Comment: You should fix the duration of the video with your range seek bar maximum length, MinValue is 0 and MaxValue is video duration. After you have to code extra logic to sync it with the video, I think you have to connect/convert screenCoord value in drawThumb with a value in seconds to trim.